# Set relative position to an image inside a block in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have a  element inside a block. The block height is 500px and the width is 100% of the screen. In this configuration, i'm aware i can see 500px of the original height (because of the overflow:hidden property i set in my css file).

The image has the following css :

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

How can set 100% in my top property to view the bottom of the image without JavaScript ?
I'm sorry for my english. This is a image to help you to understand :

[image: I need to find a way to do this]

I need to know if there is a way to do this in CSS/HTML. Before that, i used the background-position property but i switched to this for optimizing the performance of my site (in my case, the background make too repaint event). Also, i'm afraid to using JavaScript to get a relative position in pixels because my design is a fluid design (100% of the window) and the style recalculation slowing down the performances of the page.

Please note, the image is not static. (The image is different in all pages of my site and has different resolutions).

**UPDATE** In fact, `bottom:100%` set the image at 100% of the parent height. But how set the image at `-100%` to get the edge of the image?

Again, sorry for my english, and thank you for your tips!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `bottom` CSS property instead of `top`. For example, your CSS might look like this instead:

```
#imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
#imageContainer > img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Using the absolute positioning in combination with the `bottom` property will allow you to pin the bottom of the image to the nearest relatively positioned element--in this case, the containing div.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! This is working but it's weird, I need to set `bottom: 12.3%` to view the bottom of the image, and `bottom: -87.8%` to get the top. The parent element has just a `height` property set to `500px`.

Comment: **EDIT :** This is not working in fact, i have some pictures with a different resolution and I need to set `bottom:-121%` to get the top of the image.

Comment: you have to set the container's position to relative and the image positioning to absolute to get the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/u2SjC/1/

Comment: It's resolve the overflow problem, and now the `bottom:0%` worked thanks! But if i set `bottom:-100%` this is not working. This is not the absolute top of the image. http://jsfiddle.net/7qWAW/

Comment: **UPDATE** In fact, `bottom:100%` set the image at 100% of the parent height. But how set the image at `-100%` to get the edge of the image?

Answer (score 0):

From both your question and comments, it is rather confusing exactly what you are trying to achieve. However, it seems as though you are attempting to be able to show either the top or the bottom of the image at some particular time (you are not clear exactly when or how, but that may not really be relevant).

I've produced [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qWAW/1/) which has the image at the top when not hovered, and at the bottom when it is hovered. This is more to demonstrate that you need to avoid any percentages of one or the other, as those will not work correctly *since your image is constantly changing size based on the window width* (so the percentage to shift it would always be changing).

The essence of the answer, however, is similar to what cm2 posted, but what you have not grasped. **If you want the top showing, set `top: 0`, and if you want the bottom showing, set `bottom: 0`.** If you are somehow toggling between them (as my fiddle does), then you need to set the opposite one to `auto` for it to work.

If I have completely not grasped what you are trying to achieve, please correct me.

Comment: Hi @ScottS, thank you again for your intervention. This is indeed a issue I haven't resolved for the moment (please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516544/css-jquery-how-resolve-the-conflict-between-top-and-bottom-property-with-jquer). My image need to be resized, and positionned to avoid "overpositioning". For example, when the screen is below `1200px` the image needs to be at 25% of `top`. And if the screen is above `1200px` the image need to be at 25% of `bottom`. The problem is, I cannot make a smooth animation when I convert `top` to `bottom`. This is my issue.

Comment: If you are going to use javascript (which I thought you were trying to avoid for performance reasons) then you should be able to "calculate" the offset needed at the particular moment, and not have to "flip" between `top` and `bottom` (which is the issue your latest posting with javascript is having). I still think a percentage is not what you need to use, but an actual pixel calculation from your javascript. It sounds to me like you are going through a lot to avoid a background-image and in the end it may not really save you anything (just my opinion).

Comment: Yes indeed, I already use the pixels instead of percent. I try to get a solution with jQuery when the window is resized but this is not smooth actually, or i've some problems with the positions.