# (CSS/jQuery) How resolve the conflict between top and bottom property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, position

Someone know how convert a `bottom` position to `top` with CSS transition and jQuery?

I need to change the anchor of my image. And i have this problem. There is a conflict between `bottom` and `top`.

*EDIT* : In my scenario, the image has 100% of the width of the screen. And when the window is resized, i have a code in JS whoes get the new position of the image. If my anchor is always "top" for example, in some situations I have this hole who show-up for severals milliseconds and if I set at this moment bottom instead of top it will fix my issue. But I have this "jump" in the animation.

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb3M3/) to understand my issue.

Sorry for my English! Someone have an idea about this? Thank you !

Comment: what is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @YotamOmer, i need to change the anchor of the image to prevent some wrong positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the jumps by using a class, and removing the inline style as you go, like so:

```
if ( image.hasClass("bottom") ) {
    image.css("bottom", "").animate( { top: "0" } , 1000, function(){
        image.removeClass("bottom");
    });
} else {
    image.css("top", "").animate( { bottom: "0" } , 1000, function(){
        image.addClass("bottom");
    });
}
```

and add a css class

```
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

as per http://jsfiddle.net/rZPq3/

edit for cross-browser:

```
    var top = image.position().top + 'px';
    var bottom = image.parent().height() - image.height() + 'px';

    if (image.hasClass("bottom")) {
        image.finish().css({ "bottom": "", "top": top }).animate({ top: "0px" }
            , 500, function () { image.removeClass("bottom"); });
    } else {
        image.finish().css({ "top": "","bottom": bottom }).animate({bottom:"0px"}
            , 500, function () { image.addClass("bottom"); });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wCuuX/

Comment: Hi @DomDay and thank you for your help. Your fiddle doesn't work with Google Chrome. I tested on Firefox it's worked! If you have a solution for Google Chrome, It could be my solution!

Comment: looks like chrome wont animate unless the starting top or bottom property is explicitly set before the animate. so try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wCuuX/

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with one of the properties to avoid conflicts. I changed your fiddle to use `top` only and using a class to toggle the value instead.

```
var toggle = $("button#toggle");
var image = $("div img");
toggle.click(function () {
    image.toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

See [updated test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8NBX/).

Comment: Hello @MarcusEkwall and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I need to change my anchor to prevent a wrong position of my image (I'm sorry, i have difficults to explain because of my poor English...). In my scenario, the image has 100% of the width of the screen. And when the window is resized, i have a code in JS whoes get the new position of the image. If my anchor is always "top" for example, in some situations I have this hole who show-up for severals milliseconds and if I set at this moment `bottom` instead of `top` it will fix my issue. But I have this "jump" in the animation.

Comment: Why not use `bottom` only then?

Comment: @Fresheyeball Hi! If I use `bottom` my problem is the same, just inverted (I have a hole at the top of the image at some cases).